# Salesforce Email Template IF statement

Tags: html, salesforce, apex, email-templates

I am getting an error saying "Error: Syntax error. Missing '=' "
  It looks like I am doing this right, but I know it's wrong. I'm trying to do an IF statement to determine what to put in the subject line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="{!if(relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Needs_Encryption__c = true, [encrypt] {!relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Name} {!relatedTo.Action__c} Confirmation for {!relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Event__r.Sponsoring_Facility__r.Name},{!relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Name} {!relatedTo.Action__c} Confirmation for {!relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Event__r.Sponsoring_Facility__r.Name})}" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Enrollment__c" >
<messaging:HTMLEmailBody >
<c:RenderAccountLogoInEmail accountID="{!relatedTo.Event_Session__r.Event__r.Sponsoring_Facility__c}"/>
<c:EnrollmentConfirmationLetter medium="Email" enrollmentRecord="{!relatedTo}" enrollId="{!relatedTo.Id}"/>
</messaging:HTMLEmailBody>
```